# Exception GetCatalogEntityLanguages during the rebuild of sitecore_master_index (Sitecore 9.0.1)

Tags: indexing, sitecore-commerce

We were able to import our products from Sitecore Commerce to the Sitecore CMS (saved as virtual items), and I would like to search for these products using the Sitecore Search. So I rebuild the Sitecore_master_index using the "indexing manager" in the control panel, unfortunately the rebuild stopped after processing the 20000 items and showed me the below error

---

```
Job started: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_master_index|#Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: item
   at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(Object argument, String argumentName)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.Search.Crawlers.CatalogCrawlerBase`1.GetCatalogEntityLanguages(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.Search.Crawlers.CatalogCrawlerBase`1.GetItem(TEntity catalogEntity)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.Search.Crawlers.CatalogCrawlerBase`1.Add(IProviderUpdateContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.FlatDataCrawler`1.RebuildFromRoot(IProviderUpdateContext context, IndexingOptions indexingOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex.PerformRebuild(Boolean resetIndex, Boolean optimizeOnComplete, IndexingOptions indexingOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex.Rebuild(Boolean resetIndex, Boolean optimizeOnComplete)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.JobRunner.RunMethod(JobArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.Job.DoExecute()
   at Sitecore.Jobs.Job.ThreadEntry(Object state)
```

---

I assume that the index was crawling all the items until it started to crawl the commerce products and some items are maybe null or something like that.

I hope that someone could help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similair and what helped me was

1. Login Sitecore shell -> Desktop -> Content Editor
2. On Commerce tab click Delete Data templates
3. On Commerce tab click Refresh Commerce Cache
4. On Commerce tab click Update Data templates
5. Go to Index Manager and rebuild the index(Master one).

Best regards
Christian

Comment: Hi Christian, sorry for the delay. Unfortunately, my index still not rebuilding until the end. But it was able to index some products so i can work on my tasks. I will to restore my database and i will let you know if it helped. Thenks a lot.